# What's with the favicon?

Tags: discussion, design, favicon

The current favicon(s) are a menace to society.

They don't sufficiently reflect the purpose of the sites to me. I look at them and I don't immediately think "Computer Science."

I think we should put more effort into this, regardless of the fact that it's still in beta, let alone private beta. Even the generic favicons of the other betas look nicer (with the grid and one or two letters from the site name).

So yeah, we can do better. I personally can't think of anything, but let this be a suggestion depot of sorts.

Comment: I don't mind the icon. It's temporary, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all beta sites have an icon that is made of one to three letters reflecting the site's name. I don't see how the icon for a CS site could be better than “CS”.

The site is different from most other betas because CS was the first beta launched under the [new beta design](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/your-new-beta-theme); the one with the grid as a background is the old beta design. At the moment, only [Jewish Life and Learning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) has switched to the new beta design.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like we got an entirely new beta style. Criticism towards the new style should probably be on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Site-specific styles are only created after leaving (public) beta.

Comment: Guess I need to bring it up with them. The speech bubble thing is just horrendous...

Comment: @Purmou Speech bubbles are [kind of our thing](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos).